# SLIME, SBCL, and EMACS setup not resulting in expected output

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime, sbcl

I just set up Slime and am immediately noticing some issues I can't seem to resolve.

[image: first]

This is the result I get when I try to evaluate and print foo (C-c C-p)
I thought this would return 6 instead of the previous defined value of foo which was 2...Seems to not be updating??

However, if I change foo to the following, this is what I get...

[image: second]

I'm not quite understanding what SLIME is doing... or how to get basic evaluations down... Any tips? Seems I am missing a major concept in either Lisp or SLIME/Emacs

Comment: putting images on imgur is unreadable, can't you just copy / paste the code expressions and their output in the question?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you compiled `foo` but did not evaluate the new definition.